# Text based cards tracker

Tags: text, card-game, image-processing, automation

I wish to build a card tracker that reads in game text and keeps track on the cards that are out.

Like an [Overwolf](https://overwolf.github.io/docs/start/sample-app-overview) app, but for a card game.  I mailed Overwolf and asked what are my options, they suggested to use *image recognition*.  However, it sounds complex (and I luck any experience in it).  Is there a simple way to do it?

The tracker that I want to build is for [Twilight struggle](https://store.steampowered.com/app/406290/Twilight_Struggle/) and I would like to automate [this card counter](https://david.mcwebsite.net/ts/) such that It will track the cards that been played from the a text box in the game that state their name.

[image]

Comment: If the game doesn't expose an API for you to gather this information through, then yes, image recognition or a low-level GPU detour to try to identify the bits of font texture used are probably your best bets. How have you tried acting on the advice you got from the Overwolf devs so far? Where specifically did you run into an obstacle we can help you with?

Comment: Yes, the game does not expose an API.  Before I dive into this unknown ocean of image recognition, I wanted to know I am not missing an easier option.

Comment: None of the options will be "easy," but that's par for the course in game development. ;)

Comment: Please note that in many games, card counting is considered to be a form of cheating - casinos will frequently ban players who are believed to be card counting. As game developers, we often have an interest in making it difficult for players to use external tools to gain an advantage over other players in our games. So you may find users here are reluctant to answer a question like this one.

Comment: Right, however in this game (like in Bridge) counting the 110 cards is a skill all the good players poses.

Comment: Great. Then be a good player like them, and you won't need an external tool. ;) A tool that lets a not-so-good player beat a good player is often considered to be a cheat. See, for example, aim bots. Good aim is a skill that all the good players in an FPS game possess. If a weak player uses an aim bot to compete with good players, that's called cheating.

Comment: you’ve got a point